# Creation of a rectangle with texture fails

Tags: opengl, textures, opengl-3, texture2d

I want to draw a simple rectangle in OpenGL 3.0 with a texture on it. As starting point I use the example from https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/1.getting_started/4.2.textures_combined/textures_combined.cpp but with some modifications:

- all done for GLSL 1.3
- no colours in vertex-array
- only one texture instead of two overlapping ones

So I modified this code as follows. The vertex shader:

```
#version 130
in vec3 aPos;
in vec2 aTexCoord;
out vec2 TexCoord;
uniform mat4 inputTransform;
void main()
{
   TexCoord=vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
   gl_Position = inputTransform * vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 130
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D texture1;
void main()
{
   FragColor=texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}
```

-> both of them compile without errors

My vertex coordinates are arranged in one array making use of x,y,z,u,v:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

The GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP-based rectangle (without UV-coordinates and without the texture-stuff) works well and has the correct size but as soon as I apply the texture coordinates and function calls to it, nothing more than a very tiny triangle is drawn.

So I'd guess something goes wrong with the coordinates in my vertex array. But...what exactly could be wrong here?

Update: my VBO/VAO setup (simplified, so error handling code is not shown):

```
gl3Element->shaderProgram=glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(gl3Element->shaderProgram, m_gl3TexVertexShader);
glAttachShader(gl3Element->shaderProgram,m_gl3TexFragmentShader);
glLinkProgram(gl3Element->shaderProgram);
glDeleteShader(m_gl3TexFragmentShader);
glDeleteShader(m_gl3DynColourFragmentShader);
glUseProgram(gl3Element->shaderProgram);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &gl3Element->VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &gl3Element->VBO);
```

...and the texture-specific stuff to sue them:

```
glGenTextures(1, &imgEntity->m_glTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, imgEntity->m_glTexture);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,transImage->GetWidth(),transImage->GetHeight(),0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,transImage->GetData());

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, imgEntity->m_glTexture);
```

Comment: Are you sure that the attribute indices are 0 and 1? Use [`glGetAttribLocation(program, "aTexCoord")`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml) to get the attribute index.

Comment: @Rabbid76 yes and no, the attributes have been 0 and 1 accidentally - so correcting this part of the code does not solve the problem

Comment: Show us your vbo/vao set up

Comment: @Nadir question edited/extended

Comment: You said you were using the script in the link as the base, but you are rendering with GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP. Can you also post your render code? Remember that for best help you should post a minimun, verifiable example of your program.

Comment: @Nadir the point is, when I render the rectangle without all the texture-stuff, it looks good, means it is realyl a rectangle of the desired size. Only when I add the UV-coordinates and related texture code, the whole geometry of this rectangle is damaged and there is only a small triangle left - so I'd assume there is no problem with my method of calculation of the base geometry but with the additional coordinates?

Comment: What you describe seems like the data you are sending to the GPU or the way you are telling it to render it through `glDrawElements` or `glDrawArrays` is wrong.

Comment: Show you vertex array and the [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) call!

Comment: @Rabbid76 finally I got it working somehow...I stripped it back to the plain, non-textured model and then re-added all the texture-code step by step until it worked. No idea what is different, but now it is working (except a small problem with the UV-mapping). So thanks for all of your help, it at least pushed me into the right direction!